# Makefile/latexmk dropping special chars issue

Tags: makefile, latex

#### Problem

This is my Makefile:

```
SRC=src/main.tex
DST_DIR=bin

ENGINE=latexmk
FLAGS=-synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -xelatex -cd -outdir=../$(DST_DIR)

all:
    $(ENGINE) $(FLAGS) -usepretex="\def\foo{1}\def\bar{0}" -jobname="all" $(SRC)
```

When I run target `all`,

```
$ make all
latexmk -synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -xelatex -cd -outdir=../bin -usepretex="\def\foo{1}\def\bar{1}" -jobname="all" src/main.tex
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 20 November 2021, version: 4.76.
Latexmk: Changing directory to 'src/'
Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex'...
Rule 'xelatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'main.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'xelatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -no-pdf -synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder --jobname="all" -output-directory="<my-project-dir>/bin"  "deffoo1defbar1\input{main.tex}"'
------------
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `deffoo1defbar1'.
<to be read again>
                   \let
<*> deffoo1defbar1\input
                        {main.tex}
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit)
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again>
                   \let
<*> deffoo1defbar1\input
                        {main.tex}
```

You can see pretex `\def\foo{1}\def\bar{1}` was correctly delivered to latexmk, but changed to `deffoo1defbar1` on executing xelatex command, i.e. backslashes and braces are ignored.

What could be the possible problem and solution to this issue?

#### What I've tried so far

- Executed the whole command(below) directly, instead of using latexmk: Worked
- Substitued actual values to macros on Makefile: Not worked (Same error)
- Executed on another Windows device: Worked

```
$ latexmk -synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -xelatex -cd -outdir=../bin -usepretex="\def\foo{1}\def\bar{1}" -jobname="all" src/main.tex
```

#### Additional Mysterious Results

I have Makefile A for project A, Makefile B for project B, and both latexmk command in Makefiles uses pretex with backslashes and braces. I also have two Windows 10 devices X and Y. When I run Makefiles on my devices...

- Run Makefile A on device X: Not works (the problem in the post)
- Run Makefile A on device Y: Works
- Run Makefile B on device X: Works
- Run Makefile B on device Y: Works

I have no idea why only Makefile A does not work on only device X.

Comment: Like @KJ already pointed out, using different output directories is like playing with fire. It might be nice to watch the candle, but don't complain if your whole house catches fire. If you really must do such a thing, consider using ltx2any https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any This avoids most problems.

Comment: Please provide the installed/used versions of Make and shell. You can detect the shell that is used at runtime by putting an "$(info $(SHELL))" line at the beginning of your makefile. Any chance that device X uses old DOS shell vs PowerShell on device Y?

Comment: @Vroomfondel Make versions are both 3.8.1 and shells are both Windows cmd. I also tried powershell on device X, which did not work as well.

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double.

Comment: @Andreas It just showed same result, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem; the problem was from "optional Unix tools" when installing git. git was installed *with* optional Unix tools on device X, *without* tools on device Y.

I reinstalled git without tools on device X, and the script worked.